# Empty row in Excel

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a excel sheet with 5 records, I have to add only first 4 cell in a row to the List of object and ignore rest of the cells. If the first 4 cell are empty or blank  then I need to ignore that row and did not add into object.The catch is there are some records where in row first 4 cell are empty but after that cell have some value. I don't want to include those rows in the object. I have tried to put a piece of code:

```
public static boolean isRowEmpty(Row row){
         for(int c = row.getFirstCellNum(); c<row.getLastCellNum();c++){
             Cell cell = row.getCell(c);
             if(cell!=null && cell.getCellType()!=Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK){
                 return false;
             }
         }
         return true;
    }

if(isRowEmpty(row)==false){
   compList.add(compItem);
}
```

This piece of code works only when row is empty and isRowEmpty() method returns true. So far good, it didn't add value to the list. If the first 4 cell are blank and rest cell have value in a row, isRowEmpty() returns false and null value is set to list of object. Can somebody suggest me a solution to fix it?

Comment: I'm not trying to mock your english, but I'm finding it hard to understand the question. Might be useful to add a diagram to illustrate the different cases.

Comment: @Kevin I have tried to edit my query. In case you are still not able to get please let me know where is the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking all the elements in the row. If you limit the number of elements checked to first 4 in the row, you'd achieve the expected results.

```
public static boolean isRowEmpty(Row row){
         int firstCol = row.getFirstCellNum();
         for(int cnt = 0; cnt<4 ; cnt++){
             Cell cell = row.getCell(firstCol+cnt);
             if(cell!=null && cell.getCellType()!=Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK){
                 return false;
             }
         }
         return true;
    }

if(isRowEmpty(row)==false){
   compList.add(compItem);
}
```

Comment: Again, I'm not entirely sure what the question is. But this code would skip the first column(s) if empty. So the code would test cells (0, 4), (1, 5), (2, 6), etc.

Comment: We are keeping the row constant, so if we start at (0,4), then the subsequent cells would be (0,5),(0,6) and (0,7)

Comment: this line would change your starting index `int firstCol = row.getFirstCellNum();`

Comment: Thanks @SendhilkumarAlalasundaram I have tried your piece of code & it worked for my requirement. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not entirely sure what the question is. My best guess is that you want to inspect the first 4 columns of each row. If the 4 cells are blank, the row is ignored.

The issue is when cells exist in the columns that come after the forth column, they are added to the list (instead of ignoring the row).

If that is the case, then this should help:

```
public static boolean isRowEmpty(Row row){
         for(int c = row.getFirstCellNum(); c < 4 && c < row.getLastCellNum(); c++){
             Cell cell = row.getCell(c);
             if(cell!=null && cell.getCellType()!=Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK){
                 return false;
             }
         }
         return true;
    }

if(isRowEmpty(row)==false){
   compList.add(compItem);
}
```

Comment: The above code is fine, but might not work if the firstCellNum column is not 0.

Comment: How so? If the first cell does not exist, its an automatic empty?

Comment: Please have a look at my answer and comment on whether it would also work for the case where the first element in a row is empty. - Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it not possible that the first element in the row in the user's configuration is column other than 1? For e.g: column 7. The user in this instance would check if elements in columns 7-10 are all blank.

Comment: @SendhilkumarAlalasundaram That is true, yes. I was under the impression that OP did not want that behavior though.